# Python numpy: floor and ceil decimal values with variable precision (for colorbar of multiple batch plots)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, floor, ceil

To plot multiple figures in a batch mode, the aim is to define the rounded range for colorbar using `np.floor()` and `np.ceil()`. However, if the minimum range is 1.2e-5 then `np.floor(1.2e-5)` gives 0. instead of 1.e-5, and so on. Precision function cannot be used because there are decimals values and the rounding precision is variable in the loop depending on the number of exponent as shown in this example:

```
print('#Each row has the colorbar range to be floored and ceiled for each plot')
print('#values [x]')
x=np.array([[-6.880367e-05, 5.7156103e-03],[-0.18, 101.1]])
print(x)

print('#Get exponent of each decimal value [exp]')
exp=np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x))).astype(int)
exp[exp>0]=0
print(exp)

print('#Get exponent inverse [expi]')
expi=10**abs(exp).astype(float)
print(expi)

print('#Values to the power of 0 [x0]') 
x0=x*expi
print(x0)

print('#Floor and ceil values to the power of 0 [x0fc]') 
x0fc=np.transpose([np.floor(x0[:,0]),np.ceil(x0[:,1])])
print(x0fc)

print('#Convert back to original exponent [xfc]') 
xfc=x0fc/expi
print(xfc)

print('#Loop [xfc] to get colorbar range for each plot')
for row in xfc:
    print("plt.clim({})".format(str(row)))
```

This code will do the job and give the floored and ceiled ranges as needed:

```
#Each row has the colorbar range to be floored and ceiled for each plot
#values [x]
[[-6.8803670e-05  5.7156103e-03]
 [-1.8000000e-01  1.0110000e+02]]
#Get exponent of each decimal value [exp]
[[-5 -3]
 [-1  0]]
#Get exponent inverse [expi]
[[1.e+05 1.e+03]
 [1.e+01 1.e+00]]
#Values to the power of 0 [x0]
[[ -6.880367    5.7156103]
 [ -1.8       101.1      ]]
#Floor and ceil values to the power of 0 [x0fc]
[[ -7.   6.]
 [ -2. 102.]]
#Convert back to original exponent [xfc]
[[-7.00e-05  6.00e-03]
 [-2.00e-01  1.02e+02]]
#Loop [xfc] to get colorbar range for each plot
plt.clim([-7.e-05  6.e-03])
plt.clim([ -0.2 102. ])
```

Yet this seems like a very lengthy code for each a simple task. Is there an easier way to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it much more efficient. By combining a few statements and trimming some unnecessary `astype` calls, it can be made a bit shorter:

```
es = 10**np.floor(np.log10(abs(x))) # [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-1, 1e+2]
es[es > 1] = 1 # [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-1, 1.0]
for (xlo, xhi), (elo, ehi) in zip(x, es):
    xhi = np.ceil(xhi/ehi) * ehi
    xlo = np.floor(xlo/elo) * elo
    print(f'clim({xlo:.6g}, {xhi:.6g})')
```

Note that anything involving matplotlib will be many orders of magnitude slower than whatever you could vectorize here, so there is no point in vectorizing this code.

Also, you can ask yourself whether having a colorbar range like `[-3e-5, 102]` is really that useful. Ticks (on colorbars or axes) are easier to read if they are at multiples of 1, 2, or 5. If you must show the actual minimum and maximum, you can do that as a text annotation:

```
ax.text(0.05, 0.05, f'min={xmin:.3g}, max={xmax:.3g}', 
        transform=ax.transAxes))
```